# Vim arrow keys not working after accidental iTerm reset

Tags: vim, iterm2

I am using vim (8.0.705) in iTerm2 (build 3.1.5) in MacOSX.

When I accidentally hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> in the iTerm window (meant to reload a browser window), the terminal gets reset.

From this point the arrow keys in vim are not usable, other commands keep working. What is the reason and how can I re-enable the arrow keys?

Comment: Why the downvote? Wrong community?

Comment: People like to downvote without supporting with a comment why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer 1:** :!clear

**Answer 2:** Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to detach screen from your terminal, then run screen -D -R to reattach. This should make your arrow keys work again.

**Answer 3:** If you're not in screen, but just in Vim, then you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and type fg for the same effect.

**Source:** https://superuser.com/questions/800088/why-does-cmd-r-mess-up-vim-on-the-mac-what-is-it-actually-trying-to-do

Comment: Thanks. I will actually use `:!clear` instead (also from your URL).

Comment: Yes, multiple answers there, didn't want to spam answer section, so link was there for reference and further reading.